# UITableView Index Tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, indexing

I am looking for a clear concise UITableView Index tutorial, all suggestions are welcome even examples but I am thinking tutorial links would be nice.

I have been searching google but am hoping someone here has something i have not found yet.

Comment: What kind of tutorial are you looking for? What functionality from UITableView are you looking for? What's wrong with Apple's sample code?

Comment: opps I had it in my title but not my question, I am looking specifically on how to create an alphabetized Index for fast scrolling of large lists.